# How to get chatter feed of Case in single SOQL query?

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to get chatter feed in single SOQL query as below:

```
[Select id, Casenumber, (Select id, Title From FeedItems) From Case]
```

But its not working.

Is it even possible? Or else should I get it in separate SOQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationship name for feed items is `Feeds`, not FeedItems. The below query should work:

```
[SELECT Id, CaseNumber, (SELECT Id, Title From Feeds) From Case]
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  This helps to get around the dreaded: `ERROR: Implementation restriction: FeedItem requires a filter by Id` for anyone for whom this extra bit of search engine juice would benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You can query them like

```
Select id,title,body from casefeed
```